# Компиляция файла C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Возможно ли комплировать файлы C# без Visual Studio. И есть ли более удобная альтернатива Visual Studio

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: [dotnet build](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build). "Удобная" - для C# их, по сути, две: 1 - Visual Studio. 2. JetBrains Rider, все остальные, это "блокноты на стероидах", в которых вы больше замучаетесь, чем напишете.

Comment: Visual Studio - это IDE, компилятор - это отдельное ПО. Вы хоть в командной строке можете компилировать и писать код в блокноте.